# Need help on a sybase query

Tags: sql, sybase

I am using the below query to display the records,but the query is returning the duplicate records if the submitted date has a different time stamp e`x:(07/30/2012 08:13:00 PM and 07/30/2012 08:14:00 PM)`
 I need the time stamp to be displayed in Submitted date at the same time I don't want duplicates because of the `group by clause convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)).` It should only take the date part not the date with time stamp
Any help to change the query to fit into this requirement will be appreciated.

```
SELECT  clm.REPRESENTATIVE as EMPLOYEE_ID , rep.USER_NM as EMPLOYEE_NAME,fac.SUBMITTED_BY as SUBMITTER_ID, srp.USER_NM as SUBMITTER_NAME,clm.CLAIM_AM as CLAIM_AM, sum(trn.ADJUSTED_AM) as SUBMITTED_AMOUNT,

**convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)) as SUBMITTED_DATE,**


csc.CLM_SCENARIO_DESC as SCENARIO_DESC, clm.CLAIM_TP as CLAIM_TP,fac.ACTION_ID as ACTION_ID, cac.ACTION_DESC as ACTION_DESC,  clm.CLAIM_NB as CLAIM_NB, cmp.CLAIM_ID as CLAIM_ID,cust.CUST_SGMNT_ID as CUST_SGMNT_ID,(CASE WHEN sum(trn.adjusted_am) <= 100000 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) as APPROVABLE, clm.LIABILITY_60DAYS_FLAG as LIABILITY_60DAYS_FLAG 


 FROM LIB clm, Book trn, CUST cust, FIN fac, secdbp01..SEC_USER rep, secdbp01..SEC_USER srp, ADO_CLM_SCENARIO_CD csc, ADO_CLAIM_ACTIONS cac, LCM_CLAIM_MAP cmp  


WHERE clm.CLAIM_NB = trn.CLAIM_NB  AND 
clm.CLAIM_NB = cust.CLAIM_NB  AND 
trn.STATUS_FLAG = 'P'         AND trn.TRAN_DISP = 'F'           AND 
trn.CLAIM_NB = fac.CLAIM_NB   AND
trn.POSTING_DT = fac.POSTING_DT   AND 
trn.TRANSACTION_ID = fac.TRANSACTION_ID  AND 
trn.BATCH_ID = fac.BATCH_ID   AND 
srp.USER_ID <> 'R300726'  AND 
clm.REPRESENTATIVE = rep.USER_ID  AND
srp.USER_ID = fac.SUBMITTED_BY  AND 
clm.CLM_SCENARIO = csc.CLM_SCENARIO  AND
clm.CLAIM_NB = cmp.REFERENCE_NUMBER  AND
fac.ACTION_ID = cac.ACTION_ID  AND 
clm.PROGRESS_CD IN ('03','04','15')  AND
isnull(clm.TRAINING_CLM_FLAG,'N') = 'N'  AND 
(clm.CLAIM_AM >= 0 AND 
clm.CLAIM_AM <= 1000) 

GROUP BY clm.REPRESENTATIVE, rep.USER_NM, fac.SUBMITTED_BY, srp.USER_NM, clm.CLAIM_AM,clm.CLAIM_NB,
**convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)),**

csc.CLM_SCENARIO_DESC, 
clm.CLAIM_TP, fac.ACTION_ID, cac.ACTION_DESC, cmp.CLAIM_ID, cust.CUST_SGMNT_ID, clm.LIABILITY_60DAYS_FLAG 
HAVING sum(trn.ADJUSTED_AM) <= 10000000
ORDER BY SUBMITTER_NAME asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(11), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116))
```

instead of

```
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116))
```

Comment: If I use convert(datetime, convert(varchar(11), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)) Time stamp will be 00:00:00 (2012-07-30 00:00:00)
 I want the time stamp to be displayed

Comment: **Which** timestamp do you want to be displayed? Does MIN(convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)) ) suffice for the display?

Comment: yes, Atleast hours and minutes(2012-07-30 18:10:00).if we can display seconds also that will be great.
If I use convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)),th group by clause considering it as different records since the time stamp is different thus diplaying duplicate records

Comment: Yes, but when you have two different times, which do you want?

Comment: Which ever is first submitted i.e the minumum of the two

Comment: Then select `MIN(convert(datetime, convert(varchar(17), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)) )` and group on `convert(datetime, convert(varchar(11), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116))`

Comment: Thanks alot .Its working .
So the group by will consider only the date part not the time stamp
I will change this to MIN(convert(datetime, convert(varchar(20), fac.SUBMISSION_DT, 116)) ) to display seconds also